# Hinge joint annoying wheels rotation in Unity

Tags: rotation, unity

I try to made a little skate game prototype in Unity 5 and I just encountered an issue. I added a hinge joint between the board and each of the wheels couples (front and behind) so the board can move forward. My problem is that when I try to rotate a wheels couple around the red axis (see picture below), the hinge joint seems to hindered the rotation, however I'm not sure. Is someone see how to do the trick ?

Here is a sample of my source code (0 index is the front couple of wheels, 1 is the behind) :

```
private void Turn(float hAxis) {
        wheelsTransform[0].Rotate (wheelsTransform[0].right * hAxis * turnAngle * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
        wheelsTransform[1].Rotate (wheelsTransform[1].right * hAxis * -turnAngle * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

[image: The wheels are joined to the board]

Comment: Can you post an image of your HingeJoint setup? Also if you want rotation I recommend you to have a look at Spring Joint

Comment: @EvilTak Thanks for the tip, I finally found an other approach which is to use WheelCollider (easier). However it's still difficult for me to parameterize the component :/